# How can i delete both relation with signle hit

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to delete both table data with array list.
Favorites id as primary and  FavoriteProducts favorite_id is foreign key of Favorites ids.

```
 Favorites::whereNotIn('id',array_keys($request->edit_fav_list))
           ->where('user_id',$this->user)->delete();
 FavoriteProducts::whereNotIn('favorite_id',array_keys($request->edit_fav_list))
                   ->where('user_id',$this->user)->delete();
```

Comment: You can use mysql on delete constraints on your migrations. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: if($favorites = Favorites::whereNotIn('id',array_keys($request->edit_fav_list))
                   ->where('user_id',$this->user)->get())
{
                $favorites->each->delete();
}

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL you can add 'ON DELETE CASCADE' to your foreign key. put here in your favorite products migration

```
$table->foreign('favorite_id')->references('id')->on('favorites')->onDelete('cascade');
```

you could add also a delete method in your favorites model. Remove first the relation before removing the parent.

```
public function delete() {
    $this->favorite_products()->delete();
    parent::delete();
}
```

Comment: I have tested with this but it delete only Favorites model data.
public function delete() {
    $this->favorite_products()->delete();
    parent::delete();
}

Comment: you have to put this relationship favorite_products in your favorite model

Comment: Yes i have added but favorite_products couldn't delete.
**Favorites::whereNotIn('id',array_keys($request->edit_fav_list))
           ->where('user_id',$this->user)** it will get multipal records i think i have to use foreach in model inside delete() function.